# Misaligned Shared or Local Address

Tags: cuda-gdb

I am using cuda-memcheck for checking for memory errors. A simple question.
What exactly means *Misaligned Shared or Local Address* ?

Answer (score 3):

Additional information on CUDA-MEMCHECK errors can be found in [CUDA-MEMCHECK User Manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/cuda-memcheck.pdf).

Misaligned address exceptions occur when the address does not meet the natural alignment of the data access size.

```
error if (address & (access_size_in_bytes - 1))
```

For example if you tried to perform a 32-bit shared load from address 0x1 you would receive a misaligned address exception. The address needs to be a multiple of 4.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense, and i located the problem issue. Was trying to read a short as an int, and that caused the problem...Thanks